# Wordpress first run show a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I downloaded the lates wordpress version then uncompressed it.
Because I had already an old version of wordpress, I have wp tables on my local server.
Anyway, I don't think it comes from the old content.

After that, I set up the right server and database values in the "wp-config.php" file.
Then, when I wanted to run WordPress (myblog/index.php), nothing happens and, worse, a 404 error.

I thought it was my easyphp server, so I uploaded the whole database and wordpress on my website.
Nothing but a 404 error page again even if the file does exist!

Can you help me please? should I activate something to enable the first run?

Thank you very much.
Regards.

Comment: I try each answer then choose the right answer.
If no solution is found, I don't accept answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you

1) Upload the files to the correct location on the server?
2) Upload the correct files?  (e.g  are the actual WordPress files contained in a sub folder?
3) Ensure the correct privileges are set on the folder and files?
4) Follow the instructions in the downloaded package (e.g. run install.php)?

Comment: I installed WordPress again ... now the problem is to migrate the former database :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the install script? After copying the files to the server, you must run the install script at `myblog/wp-admin/install.php`

Answer (score 0):

try and go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and just click "Save Changes" and see if that helps